# Giving delay inside for loop execution

Tags: android, google-maps, delay

I have a for loop, inside which I'm calling a method to show the poi's in map. Now what I am trying to do is to show each poi in a sequence. I mean now the for loop completes at a stretch and at last is presented with the final output.

But I want it to be in order, that mean each time for loop iterates I should be able to see the animation where these geopoints are moving from place to place.

Here is my code,

```
 for (i=currentPOIindex;i<arraypoi.size();i++) {
            poi = arraypoi.get(i);
            latitude = poi.getLatitude().toString();
            longitude = poi.getLongitude().toString();
            placename = poi.getPlaceName().toString();
            mapdescription = poi.getPoiDecsription().toString();
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
            lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
            //use the poiIndex to identify which poi is highlighted
            itemizedOverlay.poiIndex = i;
            geopoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geopoint,fitTextToMapCallout(placename), fitTextToMapCalloutDescription("hello"));
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
           //this method is meant to move to each geopint one by one. 
           //And I am trying to give a delay before this method is called
            moveToPOI(i);
        }


  public void moveToPOI(int currentPOI) {
    try {
        AudioMapOverLay overlay = (AudioMapOverLay) mapOverlays.get(currentPOI);
        poi = arraypoi.get(currentPOI);
        latitude = poi.getLatitude().toString();
        longitude = poi.getLongitude().toString();
        placename = poi.getPlaceName().toString();
        lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
        lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        geopoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
        overlay.onForwardOrRewind(currentPOI, overlay);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I tried using Thread.sleep(long ms); But it is not the solution, can any one tell me what to do?

Comment: What's wrong with Thread.sleep()?

Comment: Thread.sleep(), spoils my UI and only once geopoint gets highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have come up with the answer. @Niko and @Herry, I don't know if this is similar to your code.

here is my change,

```
     notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                testgeo();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification, 1500);
```

where testge0() is,

```
 private void testgeo() {
    poi = arraypoi.get(index);
    latitude = poi.getLatitude().toString();
    longitude = poi.getLongitude().toString();
    placename = poi.getPlaceName().toString();
    // mapdescription = poi.getPoiDecsription().toString();
    lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
    if (index == currentPOIindex) {
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.poiiconactive);
        itemizedOverlay = new AudioMapOverLay(drawable, objMapView,this);
    } else {
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mapicon);
        itemizedOverlay = new AudioMapOverLay(drawable, objMapView,this);
    }
    itemizedOverlay.poiIndex = index;
    geopoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geopoint,fitTextToMapCallout(placename),
            fitTextToMapCalloutDescription("hello"));
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    moveToPOI(index);
}
```

But thank you for your help. This is working for me

Answer (score 2):

You Should have to do some thing like this in your For Loop:

```
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
   for (i=currentPOIindex;i<arraypoi.size();i++) {
          poi = arraypoi.get(i);
          latitude = poi.getLatitude().toString();
          longitude = poi.getLongitude().toString();
          placename = poi.getPlaceName().toString();
          mapdescription = poi.getPoiDecsription().toString();
           lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
           lng = Double.parseDouble(longitude);
        //use the poiIndex to identify which poi is highlighted
           itemizedOverlay.poiIndex = i;
           geopoint = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new  OverlayItem(geopoint,fitTextToMapCallout(placename), fitTextToMapCalloutDescription("hello"));
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
       //this method is meant to move to each geopint one by one. 
       //And I am trying to give a delay before this method is called
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
      public void run() {
     //Do something after 100ms
       moveToPOI(i);

   }
  }, 100/*This is Delay Value in Milli Second set which suit for your /*);  


    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this code. Any semicolon(;) is missing here?

Comment: oh Yes due to my comment after ) we have to add ;.

Comment: this is also behaving in the same way as my earlier code. I increased the delay to 1000, but still it is moving at a stretch

Comment: What is happening is function moveToPOI(i); is called at the end of for loop, I mean after completing the entire for loop, now finally when it enters to the function movetoPOI it throws java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 46, size is 46 for the line    AudioMapOverLay overlay = (AudioMapOverLay) mapOverlays.get(currentPOI);

Comment: ok, do you want it to be UI thread or nomral thread is enough? Anyways I will try both

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9575/discussion-between-herry-and-tejas)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Handler postDelayed and Runnable which does the actual operation, inside Runnable run() you remove callbacks for that runnable and post it again to the handler. If you are getting some callbacks for the operation finished you can use that to trigger the runnable again.

```
Handler handler = new Handler()
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, MY_DELAY);
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
//do the stuff

// Check if another loop sequence is needed and start runnable again
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, MY_DELAY); }
```

Comment: as per I understood, should I put the for loop block inside run()?

Comment: moveToPOI() should be called in run method. First create items and then start the runnable outside the loop. You also need member integer in runnable to be passed to moveToPOI(index).

Comment: public void animateTo(GeoPoint point, java.lang.Runnable runnable). I recommend using this, because the runnable you pass here will be called when the animation is completed, so you can start the new animation there. You will not need the postDelayed call here.